# Java packaging on Cloud9 IDE

Tags: java, classpath, package, cloud9-ide

When programming in Java on Cloud9, how do you import a user class?

Under my workspace "java_projects", I have two directories(packages) "~/workspace/project1" and "~/workspace/project2"

There is a test1.java file in project1 that imports a class from project2:

```
package project1;
import project2.test2;

public class test1
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
            }
    }
```

But the compiler doesn't recognize the project2 package("package project2 does not exist") and will not compile.

I've looked up and tried fixing the classpath to resolve this issue but with no luck.
I feel like there is a fundamental reason for why this won't work but I have no idea. Apologies in advance for being a noob ^^;; eclipse simplified all this packaging business but I guess I'll have to learn the details to use java on Cloud9. Any suggestions/references to learning more about this is greatly appreciated~

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

You need to link the other project to current project. Follow the steps as:

- Right click on project where you need dependency project and select Build path -> Configure build path
- Select Projects tab
- Click on Add and select the other project
- Click on OK button

On the other hand, if there are dependencies i.e. third part jars included in project 1 and you want that to be automatically applied when added to current project, you need to do teh following:

- Right click on dependent project and select Build path -> Configure build path
- Click on Order and export
- Click on select all button
- Click on OK

Comment: I am using Cloud9 IDE and not eclipse by the way. I think you were referring to doing this on eclipse?

Comment: Yes. Then why do you have tag eclipse?

Comment: I thought the question made it clear that I was on Cloud9. In any case I removed the tag